# Google support for SAML 2.0 ECP

Tags: saml-2.0

Does Google supports SAML 2.0 Enhanced Client Proxy profile as an Identity Provider?

If so, what is the endpoint to be used to send messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - they don't. For application authentication, Google's path is OAuth and OpenID Connect. See their [Identity Developer](https://developers.google.com/identity/) page.

Comment: Actually Google supports SAML 2.0 as IdP (https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en). I just wonder if they support ECP profile.

Comment: As far as I am aware, only Shibboleth actively supports ECP. I've never seen it in any other commercial product.